# Hello world - Mono MWF MacOSX Application

Tags: macos, mono, x11

I was trying to run `System.Windows.Forms` `HelloWorld` application on mono 2.10.8 on MacOsX Lion.
Everything went well, unless I exported `MONO_MWF_MAC_FORCE_X11` variable.
Could anybody help me?
I want to try this application under `X11`, but I got the following message:
(I have XQuartz installed)

```
X does not support your locale
Gtk not found (missing LD_LIBRARY_PATH to libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0?), using built-in colorscheme

Unhandled Exception: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: GdipCreateFromXDrawable_linux
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdipCreateFromXDrawable_linux (intptr,intptr,intptr&)
  at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromXDrawable (IntPtr drawable, IntPtr display) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd (IntPtr hwnd) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.GetAutoScaleSize (System.Drawing.Font font) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI.GetAutoScaleSize (System.Drawing.Font font) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.GetAutoScaleSize (System.Drawing.Font font) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at HelloWorld..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) HelloWorld:.ctor ()
  at HelloWorld.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: GdipCreateFromXDrawable_linux
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdipCreateFromXDrawable_linux (intptr,intptr,intptr&)
  at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromXDrawable (IntPtr drawable, IntPtr display) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd (IntPtr hwnd) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.GetAutoScaleSize (System.Drawing.Font font) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI.GetAutoScaleSize (System.Drawing.Font font) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.GetAutoScaleSize (System.Drawing.Font font) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at HelloWorld..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) HelloWorld:.ctor ()
  at HelloWorld.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug of [newer mono versions](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2474),

it worked with older mono versions (< 2.10.5). 
You can download them from [here](http://mono-project.com/OldReleases)

Comment: @user1178325 if this response answers your question then you should mark it as the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.